# How to cancel an ongoing ISearchFolderItemFactory query

Tags: c++, windows, windows-shell

Using the ISearchFolderItemFactory, I find that the line `pEnum->Next(1, &pChildItem, &ulFetched);` can take an unbound amount of time while it searches for the next result.  This is especially painful if the query has no results, and the scope of the search is also unindexed.  Is there a way to cancel the search, or get the search results in a more asynchronous manner?  I removed error handling and cleanup for conciseness.

```
ISearchFolderItemFactory* folderSearch = nullptr;
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SearchFolderItemFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&folderSearch));
if (FAILED(hr)) { ... }

hr = folderSearch->SetScope(scopedItemArray);
if (FAILED(hr)) { ... }

hr = folderSearch->SetCondition(pc);
if (FAILED(hr)) { ... }

IShellItem* shellItem = nullptr;
hr = folderSearch->GetShellItem(IID_PPV_ARGS(&shellItem));
if (FAILED(hr)) { ... }

IEnumShellItems* pEnum = nullptr;
hr = shellItem->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pEnum));
if (FAILED(hr)) { ... }

IShellItem* pChildItem = nullptr;
ULONG ulFetched = 0;
do {
    hr = pEnum->Next(1, &pChildItem, &ulFetched);
    if (FAILED(hr)) break;
    if (ulFetched != 0) {
        LPWSTR szChildName = nullptr;
        pChildItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &szChildName);
        wprintf(L"Obtained %s\n", szChildName);
        CoTaskMemFree(szChildName);
        pChildItem->Release();
    }
} while (hr != S_FALSE);
```

Comment: I encountered this as well and could never find a clean solution - the documentation for these interfaces is outrageously bad. Eventually I ended up moving the searching to a separate process and simply terminate it when I want to abort.

Comment: you mean process, not thread, so that the OS will cleanup resources used?  That seems extreme, but thanks, I'll consider it as a last resort.  The frustrating thing is I see it working if I pass an IShellItem into FileOpenDialog->SetFolder, so I know it's possible, just that the APIs are so poorly documented.

Comment: If you find a better way I'd love to know about it :)